# In Keycloak 21, Password field is not getting displayed

Tags: authentication, keycloak

In Keycloak 21 when we add a custom authentication and make it as browser flow, the password field is not displayed.[Password field is not getting displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2QhK.png)

But post entering email and clicking on login, password field is getting displayed. How to show the password field by default
[Password field is getting displayed after clicking login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pKBD.png)

Tried searching options in Keycloak dashboard for enabling password field

Comment: Did you modify the login.ftl or login-password.ftl? If so, show us the code.